# Rename files in directory

Tags: rename

How to rename files in a directory such as the following file: `PMC21375.pdf.txt`, I need to be renamed to  `21375.txt`. i.e, I need to remove both `PMC` and `pdf` from each file name.

Answer (score 9):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)'s [`rename`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?rename) :

```
rename 's/(PMC|\.pdf)//g' *pdf.txt
```

Demo :

```
$ ls *txt
PMC21375.pdf.txt
$ rename -n 's/(PMC|\.pdf)//g' *txt 
PMC21375.pdf.txt -> 21375.txt
```

from the `shell` prompt. It's very useful, you can put some [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) code like I does in a substitution.
You can remove the `-n` (dry-run mode switch) when your tests become valids.

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`linux`)

```
$ file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename))
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Comment: This will not remove the `.pdf` from the file name.

Comment: Post edited accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Besides the rename command you can do it directly in bash (just one way of many):

```
 for file in *pdf.txt; do mv $file ${file//[A-Z.]}.txt ; done
```

Edited to show  Pinyaka  how it works:

```
hmontoliu@ulises2:/tmp/foo$ touch PCM21375.pdf.txt PCM21376.pdf.txt
hmontoliu@ulises2:/tmp/foo$ ls
   PCM21375.pdf.txt  PCM21376.pdf.txt
hmontoliu@ulises2:/tmp/foo$ for file in *pdf.txt; do mv $file ${file//[A-Z.]}.txt ; done
hmontoliu@ulises2:/tmp/foo$ ls
   21375.txt  21376.txt
```

Comment: This won't remove the `.pdf` from the filename.

Comment: have you tried it? because for me it does. Shown in the edit.

Comment: My bad. I thought it would just convert capital letters. Upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

There are several utilities for renaming files, but one of the easiest to use is `rename`. In your case, you can probably do:

```
rename PMC '' *txt
rename .pdf '' *txt
```

The first parameter is the part of the filename to replace. The second parameter is the replacement string. Here I am using `''` to represent the empty string. All following parameters are files to rename, here I used `*txt` to limit the replacement to text files.

`rename` should already be present if you are running Linux. If you are running a *BSD or OS X, you may have to install it first.

Comment: I don't thing there's a GNU `rename`. There's one from `util-linux`, and one from `perl` with different syntax. The one you're refering to looks like the one from `util-linux` that is sometimes called `rename.ul` so as not to be confused with the `rename` from `perl`, while on some other systems, `rename` is the one from util-linux and the one from `perl` is called `prename`.

Comment: Mine is the one from util-linux. I mistakenly thought it was part of GNU coreutils.

Comment: The default Debian version of rename would be something like this `rename 's/PMC// *.txt` and `rename s/\.pdf// *.txt`

Answer (score 1):

First make a backup of your files! Then basically you can use a python one-liner in the current directory with the general form:

```
python -c "import glob,os; [os.rename(fn, fn.replace('PATTERN', 'REPLACE')) for fn in glob.glob('PATH/*')]"
```

in your specific case, you can use this twice:

```
python -c "import glob,os; [os.rename(fn, fn.replace('.pdf', '')) for fn in glob.glob('*')]"
```

to remove `.pdf` and again:

```
python -c "import glob,os; [os.rename(fn, fn.replace('PMC', '')) for fn in glob.glob('*')]"
```

to remove `PMC`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`for i in *.pdf.txt; do j=${i//\.pdf/}; j=${j//PMC/}; mv $i $j; done`

The `j=${i//\.pdf/}` means to substitute `.pdf` in `$i` with nothing. Likewise with the second j assignment getting rid of the PMC.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `zsh`, that's a typical job for `zmv`:

```
zmv 'PMC(*).pdf.txt' '$1.txt'
```

(`zmv` handles potential conflicts gracefully).