# How to rename multiple file using shell script?

Tags: shell-script, rename

i just want to rename my images.

IMG_20160713_173102.jpg file to 20160713_173102.jpg

i just want to remove that IMG_ part from my filename.

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers on http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98070/rename-files-in-directory or http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102647/how-to-rename-multiple-files-in-single-command-or-script-in-unix ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use gnu command `rename`:

```
rename "IMG_" "" *.jpg
```

For more information, read its manual page by running `man rename`.